# Remove LF from every other line

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to join two lines in Notepad++. Currently, each line ends with a line feed. What I am looking to do is to join lines 1 and 2 to be all in line 1. Then I want to join the next two lines to be one line (original lines 3 and 4, which are now going to be 2 and 3, to be all in one line). I found that removing the **LF** from the end of line 1 and leaving the LF at the end of line 2 will give me the result I want. However, the file I am working on has over 30,000 lines therefore I can't do it manually. The file extension is *.txt

For example, currently it is

```
Line 1    Hello ␊
Line 2    Goodbye ␊
```

Desired result:

```
Line 1    Hello Goodbye ␊
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try dos2unix command

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I assume a text file that looks something like this (your text example is not clear):

```
Line 1 dummy text first part
Line 2 dummy text last part
Line 3 dummy text first part
Line 4 dummy text last part
Line 5 dummy text first part
Line 6 dummy text last part
```

You'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)\R(.*)`
- Replace with: `$1 $2`
- Tick the *Wrap around* option
- Search mode: *Regular expression*
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (at your own risk)

**Explanation:**

```
(.+)  # one or more characters other than a newline (as many as possible)
\R    # a newline sequence (\r\n, \r or just \n)
(.*)  # zero or more characters other than a newline (as many as possible)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Ursula - you're welcome. If an answer has helped you solve your problem feel free to mark the answer as accepted and upvote.